# How to prove that $\{A \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) : A^* = \lambda A\} = e^{-i \frac{\theta}{2}} M_{n}^H$

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for my bad english.
I hope my question is in the right category...

Let the space $E_{\lambda} = \{ A \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) : A^* = \lambda A \}$, with $\lambda = re^{i \theta}$ a complex number, $\theta \in [0,2\pi[$.

$A^*$ is the conjugate transpose matrix of $A$.

I want to prove that, with the condition $ r = 1$, $E_{\lambda} = e^{-i \frac{\theta}{2}} M_{n}^H$ with $M_n^H$ the set of Hermitian matrix (order n). I don't see how to do it...

Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Note that if $A\in E_\lambda$ then $A^* = \lambda A \implies A = \overline{\lambda}A^*$ upon taking the Hermitian conjugate of both sides. What does this tell you about the modulus of $\lambda$? Based on this, compute $(e^{i\theta/2}A)^*$ and draw the desired conclusion.